# What does ℜ symbol mean?

Tags: notation

I came across the symbol $\mathfrak{R}$ in the Kalman introduction: [Kalman Filter Intro](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/media/pdf/kalman_intro.pdf)

$$
x\in \mathfrak{R}^m 
$$
It was used in this context:

$$
    x_{k} = Ax_{k–1} + Bu_{k – 1} + w_{k – 1}
$$
What does $\mathfrak{R}$ stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means $x$ is an $m$-vector of real values. $\mathfrak{R}$ itself is the set of real numbers.

Comment: I'd like to point out that nowadays $\mathbb{R}^m$ ("blackboard bold") is much more common.

Comment: @MattL. Yes! ℜ is just bad typography.

Comment: haha great! I have seen ℝ (the blackboard bold) much more often. I didn't realize they were the same thing!